# Passing Enumerated argument

Tags: java

Im having an issue passing an enumerated value from my main to one of my classes.  My program stores information about nerds: name, nerdfactor.  It has a series of classes and subclasses.  I have a super class which is extended to 2 other classes and a third class which extends to 1 of the before mentioned subclasses.  what my program is supost to do is take filled arguments such as name, nerdfactor, and wether the nerd prefers WII, XBOX or PS3.   Bellow is a clip from my main and the beginings of my subclass.  If anyone can help me figure out how to pass the enumerated argument i'd be very grateful.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // List to keep a few nerds in
    ArrayList<GenericNerd> nerdList = new ArrayList(10);
    GenericNerd nerd = new GenericNerd("Bugger McNosePicker", 9);
    nerdList.add(nerd);

    nerd = new ConsoleGeek("Freddy where's my mommy", 9, WII); // the WII should be an enum value
    nerdList.add(nerd);
}
```

Subclass ConsoleGeek

```
public class ConsoleGeek extends GenericNerd {

    enum ConsoleType {

        WII, PS3, XBOX
    };
    private ConsoleType console;

    public void setConsoleType(ConsoleType console) {
        this.console = console;
    }
    public ConsoleType getConsoleType(){
    return console;
}


public ConsoleGeek(String name, int nerdFactor, ConsoleType console) {
    super(name, nerdFactor);
    if (name == null) {
        System.out.println("Error: GenericNerd constructor - name is null!");
        System.exit(1);
    }
       // the setNerdFactor method handles parameter range checking
    setNerdFactor(nerdFactor);

    this.name = name;
    if (console == ConsoleType.WII) {

        // make sure WII players nerd factor is less than 6!
        if (nerdFactor > 5) {
            System.out.println("Warning: " + name
                    + " Prefers WII! (setting nerdFactor to 5).");
            setNerdFactor(5);
        }
        // Make sure XBOX players nerd factor is between 3 and 8
    } else if (console == ConsoleType.XBOX) {
        if (nerdFactor < 3 || nerdFactor > 8) {
            System.out.println("Warning: " + name
                    + " Prefers XBOX! (setting nerdFactor to 8).");
            setNerdFactor(8);
        }

    }
}
```

I thought about the idea of making a new type of nerd like

```
ConsoleGeek supergeek = new ConsoleGeek(arguments)
```

but I'm pretty sure its supposed to stay in the other format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nerd = new ConsoleGeek("Freddy where's my mommy", 9, ConsoleGeek.ConsoleType.WII);
```